# How to use Opencv, qt creator, ming gw windows together?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, undefined-reference

I have been working with Opencv 3.7, Windows 8/10 and QT Creator 5.12 and MVS C++ Compiler for a long time now without any problems.

However I, if I switch my compiler to QT Mingw 73_64 C++ Compiler, building my projects does not work as all opencv references are undefined, even though under the mvs compiler it works.

I tested this on a different windows system with mingw and the same errors showed.

Is this commonly reproducible? How can one resolve this problem and work with mingw?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile OpenCV with that compiler.

Comment: Why do I have to compile OpenCV with that compiler? What does that do/achieve?